# Best way to process bootstrap-wysihtml5 output

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, wysihtml5

Im using the bootstrap-wysihtml5 rich text editor [bootstrap-wysihtml5](https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5/) which basically works as expected. 
However, I was wondering what would be the best approach to process the generated HTML output for inclusion into the DOM tree. The issue is that normal text input comes without a tag whereas all the other tags (h1, h2, ul, etc. are provided) which makes it difficult to take the output straight away.

Is there a way to avoid any additional processing? Or am I just missing the p-tags somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

For anybody finding here later (April 2015, Version 0.4.17): Just use the option

```
useLineBreaks : false
```

`false` means, every paragraph is properly and initially surrounded by `<p>...</p>`. Block commands are applied to that `<p>`.

`true` means, there is no initial `<p>...</p>` and block commands embrace with some `<div>...</div>` and more.

Answer (score 0):

I tnik better to use is tinyMCE, workd great and every new line has `<p>` tag, you can also force him to not use `<p>`, just send false in init:)